# Share session between my site and WP blog

Tags: session

I am using Yii framework for a web site and WP for a blog (don't ask why, I inherited this project). Yii is responsible for users (login/logout...), and in the blog (WP), I need to know when the user is logged in.

I tried setting session in Yii, `$_SESSION['key'] = $value`, and reading it in WP, but WP doesn't see the session: `echo $_SESSION['key']`

The domain for the site is `example.com`, and for the blog is `example.com/blog`.

Is it possible to share a session this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your init or config file.

```
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."), 100));
```

Whenever PHP sets the 'PHPSESSID' cookie, the cookie will be available to all over the site including Blog.